# Why doesn't a router forward messages to hosts on different subnets?

Tags: networking, router, subnet

I have a question about the following scenario:

Host A has been configured with a static IP of 192.168.3.123/24

Host B has been configured with a dynamic IP of 192.168.1.55/24

The router has the IP 192.168.1.1

If host A tries to ping host B, it will conclude that it is on a different subnet and instead of sending the message directly to the receiver, it will send the request to the router, which will result in a "Network Unreachable" message.

Why is it that the router doesn't forward the message to Host B?

Comment: You can't tell unless you provide information on the configuration of the router. If it's not properly configured it won't do anything.

Comment: Well, that's sort of the part i don't understand. Could you give an example of a router configured so that it wouldn't work, and one that would?

Comment: One that has routing information for both networks and one which doesn't. One which is set to actually route and one which isn't. One which does isolate directly connected devices and one which doesn't. Host A does have a default route or it doesn't. Host A has a defined route for Host B or it doesn't. In addition host A already knows host B is on a different subnet before you do a ping. Your scenario is poorly defined. It's implied that host A is connected to the router but is host B? What kind of router is it actually? Do you just look for an academic answer or do you have an actual problem?

Comment: The router is at work and I don't control it. If I change Host As subnet mask to /22 I can ping Host B. I'm asking because I want to understand more how networks work, not because I need to solve a specific problem. If the answer is that there is no way to know without admin login to the router then I'll accept that. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your router needs an IP address on each subnet it is supposed to be directly routing to/from.

Comment: To expand on what Spiff is saying, you likely don't have a route for the router attached to host B to talk to the router attached to host A. The gateway needs a list of routes to send to. It needs an entry that tells it that anything bound for 192.168.3.0/24 goes to 192.168.3.1. It also needs an iface with an IP in 192.168.3.0/24 that connects to that router. If it gets a packet bound for that network, it'll send it to that router and the router will send it to .123. This is because packets at the local level don't actually use IPs, they use MACs, so it can't send it direct to another network.